# Send event from one form to another form

Tags: c#, user-interface

I am really getting hard time to solve this seemingly easy problem:
I have one form (Child Form) with a button which when clicked should set focus the textbox on  another form (Parent Form).

I have tried to use some codes as shown below:My question is this the right aproach?
And if so how to solve this error message

> *Cannot Implicitly Convert type 'System.EventHandler' to 'ChildForm.SomeEventHandler*

```
public class ChildForm : Form
{
    public delegate SomeEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event SomeEventHandler SomeEvent;


}

public class ParentForm : Form
{
    ChildForm child = new ChildForm();
    child.SomeEvent += new EventHandler(this.HandleSomeEvent);

    public void HandleSomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.someTextBox.select();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the assignment from

```
child.SomeEvent += new EventHandler(this.HandleSomeEvent);
```

to

```
child.SomeEvent += new ChildForm.SomeEventHandler(this.HandleSomeEvent);
```

Edit 1:
It looks perfect for the use of handling an event in Parent Form when an action occurs in Child form. Though it doesn't look thread-safe.

Also take a look at [Form.Activate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Abhinav. However when I changed to: child.SomeEvent += new SomeEventHandler(this.HandleSomeEvent);

Comment: Thanks when I tried to change to: child.SomeEvent += new SomeEventHandler(this.HandleSomeEvent); the other message came up that  the type or namespace name SomeEventHandler could not be found or missing reference.

Comment: I have updated the answer with fully qualified name.

Comment: Mr Abhinav, I need your help to the above question. Why am I getting this error message after changes you suggested:"the type or namespace name SomeEventHandler could not be found or missing reference"